# Choose Production, Is there anyway to bypass it

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

Is there anyway to bypass the "Choose Production" button. Basically in my cities there are no more buildings or wonders left to build and I don't want to keep building units as it eats at my money. The only solution I have is to build a unit then delete it on completion then repeat however this seems a rather round-about way of doing it. I would of thought choosing a production would be optional that or maybe I have missed something?

Comment: Don't you have science production or something?  There's almost always an infinite production option that converts your hammers into science, or gold, or whatever.

Comment: @fbueckert I know what you are referring to I was just hoping there was a bypass until I reached those techs, I guess not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While you do have to produce something, there are a couple of techs that give you alternative options to using your production on units, wonders, or buildings:

The technology **Currency** unlocks "Wealth" which converts a percentage of your city's production directly to gold.  Similarly, **Education** allows you to produce research.  These two options are typically below the wonders group in your production menu.

You can also change the focus of your city away from production (to food, commerce, etc) which will slow down your production, while providing alternative benefits to your civilization.  Changing the improvements on your tiles can also shift the focus of a city from production to some other use - for instance, chopping down forests or demolishing a mine will reduce the production in a tile.

Comment: I am working towards the science and wealth production generators, But not there yet. Was just hoping there was a bypass until that point guess not.

Comment: @RyanWalkowski, I'm very surprised that you'd have no need for production that early in the game - building your military, workers, or settlers is probably a good strategy that early.

Comment: I have already taken out all the barbarians, city states and one other player around me that might give me problems. And I have about 8 workers currently. I'm just burning funds atm

Comment: Wow!  Perhaps it is time for a harder difficulty setting then? :)

Answer (score 0):

At the later point of the game the only thing to do is endlessly produce units because producing something for every city is mandatory, which really sucks. Because I have a maritime empire of about 20 cities, and endlessly clicking "Choose Production "and "Delete Unit" gets awfully tiring. A good alternative at this point is to make every city change science into wealth (IF you have all the technologies). I hope this helps, because it sure helped me.